# Add row to table from dropdown list selection in Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a simple dropdown with some dummy data that I would like to populate a row of a table every time I select an item from the dropdown list using knockout.

But I have a few problems:

1. The  doesn't show the options from the optionValues
2. The default LaborReservations are not showing up
3. I'm not quit sure how to add a row every time I make a dropdown selection

I have followed some of the examples on the knockout page, but can't see how to do what I would like with the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<h2>Add Labor to table</h2>
<select data-bind="options: optionValues"></select>
<br><br><br>   
<table>
    <thead><tr>
    <th>Labor name</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: labors">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        </tr> 
     </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Class to represent a row in the labors grid
function LaborReservation(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function LaborsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var viewModel = { optionValues: ["Test Labor Row 1", "Test Labor Row 2", "Test Labor Row 3"]};
    self.availableLabors = [{
        "LaborName": "Test Labor 1"
        },
        {
        "LaborName": "Test Labor 2"
        },
        {
        "LaborName": "Test Labor 3"
    }];

    // Editable data
    self.labors = ko.observableArray([
        new LaborReservation("Labor Item 1"),
        new LaborReservation("Labor Item 2")
    ]);

    self.addLabors = function() {
        self.labors.push(new LaborReservation(//want to add selected dropdown item
        ));
}

ko.applyBindings(new LaborsViewModel());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your select to some value, and subscribe to it to add to your table.  E.g.:

```
self.newValue = ko.observable();
self.newValue.subscribe(function(value) {
    self.labors.push(new LaborReservation(value));
})
```

This example does most of what you are asking as a start:

http://jsfiddle.net/NzTSU/3/

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for. Very helpful reply and jsfiddle example. Thanks!

Comment: If I would like to push an object with multiple properties, how should I do it? The example shows what I'm trying to do: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lbgraham/B5b44/)  I want to pass the selected array  to LaborReservation(). For example, if the user chooses self.availableLabors[0].description, I would like to pass self.availableLabors[0] to LaborReservation().

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks so much for your help!